# JavaPlugin cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, minecraft, spigot

I want to code a 1.18.2 Minecraft plugin using Java in the eclipse IDE. I'm pretty sure I'm using the latest versions for everything. I'm using a tutorial and when it said to put this in:

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
```

A red line shows up under JavaPlugin and it says it cannot be resolved to a type. I'm supposed to import this:

`import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;`

Everything I've googled has said to put the spigot jar in project properties > build path > libraries > add external jar which I've done, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: If you have a `module-info.java` file, delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use platform like [maven](https://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html) or [gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/what_is_gradle.html). Since Spigot 1.17 (include) it's not so easy to use spigot build as build path library.

In detail of all possibilities:

1. **Use direct file**. It's not recommended.

Since 1.17 included, the spigot jar contains others jar, and when you run the server, it copy all of them into folders. So, each files are containing part of the full spigot code :

- `bundler/libraries` contains all basic libraries such as what you want: `spigot-api-1.18.jar` or mysql connectors.
- `bundler/versions` contains the NMS part of spigot. Prefer to don't use this, but sometimes it's the only way to do what you want.

Those files (in the `bundler` folder) can be imported in eclipse such as you do for the global spigotmc.

2. Use **Maven** ([documentation](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/spigot-maven/)), and add this into your `pom.xml` file :

```xml
<repositories>
    <!-- This adds the Spigot Maven repository to the build -->
    <repository>
        <id>spigot-repo</id>
        <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <!--This adds the Spigot API artifact to the build -->
    <dependency>
           <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
           <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
           <version>1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now, to build your project, you can: right click on project -> Run As -> Maven build

3. Use **Gradle** ([documentation](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/spigot-gradle/)), and add this into your `build.gradle` file :

```
repositories {
   maven { url = 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
}
dependencies {
  // Pick only one of these and read the comment in the repositories block.
  compileOnly 'org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

To build your project, you should create a new task (on top, where you run basic Java project) and config it as you want. [More informations](https://www.journaldev.com/8118/gradle-eclipse-plugin-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use BuildTools, you can get it here: https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/buildtools/

Just do what they tell you to do, and at the end, you'll get in the spigot/spigot-api/target folder a file named 'spigot-api-$(version)-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar', that's the file you need to put in build path